# Should I use one or many CloudBlobContainer for storing images?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a few image types in my app, and I'd like to use CloudBlobContainer to store those images:

- Images of same type have the same image size.
- There will +/- 10 types of images.
- There will be not more than 1000 images per type.
- It is important for me to know the type of the image by it's location.
- Images from different categories might be presented on one page.

I'd like to create separated blob container for each image type. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Can you please explain whet you mean by `It is important for me to know the type of the image by it's location`?

Comment: What is you reasoning behind thinking about a blob container per type?

Comment: Let's say all my file names are guids. If I put them into one blob container, and then iterate thorough the list of items I wont be able to tell what is the image type of that item. I need something similar to sub folder structure:

- images/type1/
- images/type2/

Answer (score 1):

> It is important for me to know the type of the image by it's location.
>
> Images from different categories might be presented on one page.

As I known, you could name your blobs(images) with path information in their names. And this would create a **virtual directory structure** that you can manage and traverse them as a traditional file system.

`https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/photo01.jpg`

`https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/2017/photo02.jpg`

`https://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/2017/02/photo03.jpg`

And you could leverage [List Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/list-blobs) with optional `prefix` parameter, which could filter the blobs whose names beigin with the spcified prefix under the specified container.

Also, as this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-scalability-targets) mentioned about the scalability and performance targets for Azure Storage:

> Partitions affect load balancing and scalability for each of the storage services in the following ways:
>
> **Blobs**: The partition key for a blob is account name + container name + blob name. This means that each blob can have its own partition if load on the blob demands it. Blobs can be distributed across many servers in order to scale out access to them, but a single blob can only be served by a single server. **While blobs can be logically grouped in blob containers, there are no partitioning implications from this grouping**.

In my opinion, both options could meet your requirement. For more details about Blob Storage, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) and choose your development language for getting started with it.